# What is difference between Branch, WAN, Core, Enterprise Routers?

Tags: routing

While studying routing protocols is OSPF, BGP I came across Network topologies distinguishing between Branch, WAN, Core, Enterprise Routers. I am having a hard time understanding their functionality and where each of these routers sits in different offices of a company.

Comment: They will have different feature sets, but it's ultimately just just marketing. What each site/office needs will dictate what gets put there.

Comment: You might also be interested in the "Cisco Three-Layer Hierarchical Model", which divides the network into core, distribution, and access functions. https://geek-university.com/ccna/cisco-three-layered-hierarchical-model/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It it not a big or complicated concepts. Those are just marketing term but feature set can be different. Generally Core mean if your entire network connected to central switch or router it will be core switch or router. If you use same modal device in branch office it will be branch office router. WAN also same but enterprise level devices mean it can handle huge number of sessions simultaneously. Generally Enterprise level Devices are used by Large networks such as ISP, Huge companies...etc.

If you want to device for small network or home network you can use consumer grade devices.